# Decision after draw in extra time in field hockey

Tags: rules, field-hockey

I saw a play-off match in some national field-hockey league and the match ended with the teams level.

I always thought that draws were decided based on a penalty series (like soccer). In this case however, the game ended with a shoot-out where one player starts far from the goal, and tries to beat the goal keeper in a solo rush (like hockey).

Is this a new official rule, or is this a try out for this league?

Comment: I saw that also on some championship. we should check the rules about it.

Comment: I've re-added the specific date here; "yesterday" I'd confusing because this event happened in 2012, not 2018 (or 2019 or 2020...)

Comment: @PhilipKendall And I removed it earlier because it looks silly. The whole date is irrelevent to the whole question. Also, the question already lists the date it is asked, so it is superfluous.

Comment: Please see the [current discussion on meta](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/862/is-it-ok-to-use-words-such-as-yesterday-this-seasons-etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FIH trialled the one-on-one shootout method (as opposed to "from-the-spot" shots) in the 2010 Champions Trophy and Champions Challenge as well as the Azlan Shah playoffs on the 15th May 2011.

These trials were to see if it was a suitable alternative to put in place for the 2012 London Olympics.

> In the shoot-out, the striker starts the one-on-one attack against the goalkeeper from 23 yards. The striker has eight seconds to enter the striking circle and score. He is allowed to flick, push, drive or dribble past the custodian, who can come off the goalline to try and deny him a goal.
>
> Like the penalty-strokes tie-breaker, if the deadlock persists after the five mandatory attempts by each team, the shoot-out will go into sudden-death.

Following the successful trials, the FIH has adopted this rule for all classification fixtures.

See [this briefing which has more detail](http://www.umpirehockey.com/Rules_and_Briefings_17/Shootouts_to_make_FIH_debut.shtml).